# Python to convert everything to lowercase after a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that contains the following format. everything is seperated by `;` but the actual article is seperated by `;;;`.

```
audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55;;;Maar dishierdie Mense
audio1.wav;2925.32;2926.77;;;van die Padwerkers Wat
```

How do I lowercase everything after `;;;` so the output file is

```
audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55;;;maar dishierdie mense
audio1.wav;2925.32;2926.77;;;van die padwerkers wat
```

So far I have

```
import re

with open(filename, 'r') as txtfile:
        data = txtfile.read()
        re.sub(r"", lambda m: m.group().lower(), data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
fin = open("file.txt")
fout = open("output.txt", "wt")
for line in fin:
    before, after = line.split(';;;')
    fout.write(before + ';;;' + after.lower())
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Here is **output.txt**

```
audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55;;;maar dishierdie mense
audio1.wav;2925.32;2926.77;;;van die padwerkers wat
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach

**Ex:**

```
import re

data = """audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55;;;Maar dishierdie Mense
audio1.wav;2925.32;2926.77;;;van die Padwerkers Wat"""

data = re.sub(r";;;(.+)", lambda x: x.group().lower(), data)
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55;;;maar dishierdie mense
audio1.wav;2925.32;2926.77;;;van die padwerkers wat
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rsplit`, you can do:

```py
records = [
    "audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55;;;Maar dishierdie Mense",
    "audio1.wav;2925.32;2926.77;;;van die Padwerkers Wat",
]

normalized = [
    line.rsplit(";", 1)[0] + ";" + line.rsplit(";", 1)[1].lower()
    for line in records
]
```

Using a RegEx with lookbehind:

```py
import re

normalized = [
    re.sub(r"(?<=;;;).*$", lambda mo: mo.group().lower(), line)
    for line in records
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can incorporate something like this:

```py
temp_string = 'audio1.wav;2925.32;2926.77;;;van die Padwerkers Wat'

temp_string = temp_string.split(';;;')

';;;'.join([temp_string[0], temp_string[1].lower()])
```

outputs:

```
'audio1.wav;2925.32;2926.77;;;van die padwerkers wat'
```

Answer (score 0):

For every line, you can find the position of *";;;"* with **string.find(...)** and split the string in two different part depending on this position:

```
line[:line.find(";;;")]+line[line.find(";;;"):].lower())
```

How it works? Let's write an example on

> audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55;;;Maar dishierdie Mense

- `string[:position]` returns a substring from the start of our string to *position*, so `line[:line.find(";;;")]` returns "*audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55*"
- `string[position:]`returns a substring from *position* to the end of our string, so line[line.find(";;;"):] returns "*;;;Maar dishierdie Mense*". If you use `.lower()`, you can get this string in lowercase, so the output will be:

> audio.wav;2869.52;2870.55;;;maar dishierdie mense

Answer (score 0):

Assume each record takes one line.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "your filename"

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        buf = []
        for idx, n in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            sep = n.split(';;;')
            if len(sep) != 2:
                raise Exception(f"Wrong format at line {idx}")
            buf.append(sep[0] + ';;;' + sep[1].lower())

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(buf)
```